# FloatingActionButton too small on big screens

Tags: android, material-design

I'm new in Android and I'm trying to understand why my FloatingActionButton are too small on big screen resolutions, like Galaxy Tab 8.4. On my Nexus 4, the size is ok:

Nexus 4

[image: FloatingActionButton on Nexus 4]

Galaxy Tab 8.4

[image: FloatingActionButton on Galaxy Tab 8.4]

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:elevation="6dp"    
    app:layout_behavior="com.app.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
```

Comment: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

It looks well scaled to me. In both cases the button is roughly more than two lines of text.

Density-independent pixels are not really device-agnostic and can lead to slightly different results. This is nothing you should worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the size of the FloatingActionButton in XML by adding this :

```
app:fabSize="normal"
```